# How to create FOREIGN KEY relationship between tables?

Tags: sql-server

I've created a database for a project management system, but the problem is when I created the tables (users) (memberof) (team) (project) (task), I can't link the task with its user.

[image: ERD]

Comment: you should edit your question and add images inline so we don't have to go off-site to look at ads.

Comment: you have an `iduser` on the `tache` table, so why don't you just set that as a FOREIGN KEY to your `users` table?

Comment: sorry for that, i couldn't add the image they said i ve to complet 10 question.
and i didn't set the foreign key because the database ll become circled and this couldn't be as i know

Comment: added image. also, it's possible to have circular key relationships, just try it

Comment: okay then, thank you very much Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Just join the tables together on the PK/FK and then on the id_user since that is in both the task and the user table.  Since some tasks may required more than one person, it would be better in a separate table with a many-to-many relationship to the user and the task rather than in the task table as you have now.

Comment: a task can have just one user, but about joining the tables task and users together, as i know a database can not be circled, right ?